# How to make my internal callback function reactive for mobx state change?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have created a internal callback function as below.

```
render() {
    const profiles = this
      .props
      .store
      .profiles;
    const renderCell = (rowIndex: number) => {
      console.log('rendering...');

      return <Cell>{profiles[rowIndex].alias}</Cell>;
    };
    return (
      <div className="profileList">
        <Table
          allowMultipleSelection={false}
          numRows={this.props.store.profiles.size}
          isRowHeaderShown={false}
          selectionModes={SelectionModes.ROWS_AND_CELLS}
          isColumnResizable={false}
          isRowResizable={false}
          defaultColumnWidth={1024}
          onSelection={(region) => this.onSelection(region)}
        >
          <Column name="Connection Profiles" renderCell={renderCell.bind(this)}/>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

From above code, you can see that there is a `renderCell` function created inside the `render()` function. When I update the mbox state for `profile.alias` this function is not triggered. If I put the `profile.alias` under `render()` method directly, it works fine. How to make my `renderCell` reactive for state changes?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Cell` component is not external, you could decorate it with `@observer`

If it's external, you could wrap your function in observer, something like this:

```
const RenderCell = observer(({ rowIndex }) => {
    console.log('rendering...');

    return <Cell>{profiles[rowIndex].alias}</Cell>;
};
```

There's great documentation about [Understanding what MobX reacts to](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html) in their website, I recommend reading it, it helps you understand MobX better.

Comment: Does `observer(..)` returns the same react component as before? After made that change, my component is not working at all. I got an error exception: `Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead. `

Comment: You should use it as JSX component call syntax:
`<Column ...  renderCell={index => <RenderCell rowIndex={index} />} />`
Or you could use `React.createFactory(component)` syntax that are written in React documentation if you don't want to use JSX syntax: [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/legacy-factories.html)